# How can I get the name of the current branch in Gitlab CI

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, gitlab-ci

I'm setting up Gitlab CI job. I want to get the name of the current branch from a Gitlab CI job. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GitLab 9.0 and above, you have a predefined `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` environment variable you can use in your jobs.